# Finding the distance in rows within a column between current row and first row with different value than current row

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
data = data.frame(values = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,4))
```

Then I'd like to use a function within dplyr::mutate() to create a new column that will give me the distance between the current row and the first row with a different value than the current row.

I would expect the following:

```
   values target
1       1      3
2       1      2
3       1      1
4       2      4
5       2      3
6       2      2
7       2      1
8       1      2
9       1      1
10      4     NA
```

I know that with the function `dplyr::lead()` we can retrieve the value of the n-th row leading the current row. So I'm looking for kind of a reverse function which will not return the value of the nth-row, but the nth of the first row with a different value.

I thought about writing a function and iterating through argument `n` in `dplyr::lead()` and comparing the result of the returned value with the current rows value, breaking the loop if the returned value is different.

But how would I write such a function so it can be used within `dplyr::mutate()` and a dataframe context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option using `purrr::imap_dbl` and a custom function to compute the minimum distance:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)

min_lead_distance <- function(values) {
  purrr::imap_dbl(
    values, \(x, y) {
      # Absolute difference
      diff <- abs(values - x)
      # Set non-leading values to NA
      diff[seq_len(y)] <- NA
      # Check if any non NA and non zero value, if not return NA
      if (all(is.na(diff) | !diff > 0)) {
        return(NA)
      }
      # Return distance to first non-NA non-zero value
      min(which(diff > 0)) - y
    }
  )
}

data = data.frame(values = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,4))

data |>
  mutate(target = min_lead_distance(values))
#>    values target
#> 1       1      3
#> 2       1      2
#> 3       1      1
#> 4       2      4
#> 5       2      3
#> 6       2      2
#> 7       2      1
#> 8       1      2
#> 9       1      1
#> 10      4     NA

data <- data.frame(values = c(1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,2))

data |>
  mutate(target = min_lead_distance(values))
#>    values target
#> 1       1      3
#> 2       1      2
#> 3       1      1
#> 4       4      4
#> 5       4      3
#> 6       4      2
#> 7       4      1
#> 8       1      2
#> 9       1      1
#> 10      2     NA

data <- data.frame(values = c(1,1,1,1,1))

data |>
  mutate(target = min_lead_distance(values))
#>   values target
#> 1      1     NA
#> 2      1     NA
#> 3      1     NA
#> 4      1     NA
#> 5      1     NA
```

**Original code with bug**

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(purrr)

data |>
  mutate(target = purrr::imap_dbl(
    values, \(x, y) {
      diff <- abs(values - x)
      diff[seq_len(y - 1)] <- Inf
      diff[!diff > 0] <- Inf
      if (all(is.infinite(diff))) return(NA)
      
      min(which(!is.infinite(diff))) - y
    }
  ))
```

Comment: My target vector looks like `[1]  3  2  1  4  3  2  1 NA NA NA` with your code.  Is this possible?

Comment: There was an error in my code for the assignment to data. The last digit was 1 in my original post while it was 4 in the second code block where the target value was given. I corrected this. With the corrected data$values you should receive the same result as stefan pointed out.

Comment: @stefan thanks a lot for this solution, I'm still working on understanding the single steps of the function, but the result is what I expected!

Comment: @stefan, when applying your function to my actual dataframe and use case I encountered a minor mistake in your function. It works on the example in the original post, but if you apply it e.g. on `data <- data.frame(values = c(1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,2))` it will result in a wrong target. I exchanged `which.min(diff) - y` by `min(which(!is.infinite(diff))) - y` and it now works fine.

Comment: Aw. Should have tested on other data as well. I just made an edit to fix the bug and simplify the code. And added some explanatory notes.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not as concise as `purrr::imap_dbl()` but an exercise of using for-loops in R:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4)

find_next <- function(digit, x) {
  if (is_empty(x)) return(NA)
  other_digits <- setdiff(x, digit)
  if (is_empty(other_digits)) return(NA)
  min(match(other_digits, x))
}

out <- integer(length = length(x))

for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  out[i] <- find_next(x[i], tail(x, -i))
}

out
#>  [1]  3  2  1  4  3  2  1  2  1 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Borrowing from stefan, the function I wrote can also be used with `imap_*()` so the difference isn't necessarily the use of a for-loop:

```r
imap_int(values, \(x, idx) find_next(x, tail(values, -idx)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach! Guess I will stick with stefans solution because it is certain that it works with mutate and on dataframe columns.

Comment: Sure! I just added a remark that the function I wrote can also be used with `imap_*()` and thus in combination with `mutate()` and dataframes. I just wasn't aware of it :)

Answer (score 2):

I like the other solutions, but wanted to share this just in case it may be of interest.

I think you can use `rle` to create a "countdown" for groups of the same `values` - using `rev` to reverse the `sequence`.

In the example, the last value had a `target` of `NA` (no further changes in values noted at the end). For this simple example, I pad with `NA`, since the last sequence would not be counted.

```
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  mutate(target = c(rev(sequence(rle(rev(values))$lengths[-1])),
                    rep(NA, rle(rev(values))$lengths[1])))
```

**Output**

```
   values target
1       1      3
2       1      2
3       1      1
4       2      4
5       2      3
6       2      2
7       2      1
8       1      2
9       1      1
10      4     NA
```

Comment: `rle()` feels very natural for this task indeed... Interestingly, it didn't run faster than stefan's solution and even my for-loop in my benchmarks. But might be due to the fact that we are dealing with a toy dataset here.

Comment: Definitily the most elegant approach which also deals with all the knife-edge cases without the need for any checks and ... (:

Answer (score 2):

In base R we can create `rev`ersed `cumsum`s of the value sections using `ave` and replace target of the last section with `NA`.

```
> within(data, {
+   cs <- cumsum(c(0, diff(values)) != 0)
+   target <- replace(
+     ave(values, cs, FUN=\(x) rev(seq_along(x))), 
+     cs == max(cs), NA_integer_)
+   rm(cs)
+ })
   values target
1       1      3
2       1      2
3       1      1
4       2      4
5       2      3
6       2      2
7       2      1
8       1      1
9       4      1
10      1     NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(values = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of learning, a solution that combines `rle()` suggested by Ben as well as `imap_*()` used by stefan:

```r
library(tidyverse)

values <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4)
data <- tibble(values)

countdown <- function(x, idx) {
  tail <- values[idx:length(values)]
  run_lengths <- rle(tail)$lengths
  if (length(run_lengths) == 1L) return(NA)
  run_lengths[1]
}

data |> mutate(target = imap_int(values, countdown))
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>    values target
#>     <dbl>  <int>
#>  1      1      3
#>  2      1      2
#>  3      1      1
#>  4      2      4
#>  5      2      3
#>  6      2      2
#>  7      2      1
#>  8      1      2
#>  9      1      1
#> 10      4     NA
#> 11      4     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, personally I find the idea to generate a vector of sequences by combining `rle()` with `sequence()` even more elegant :)